# “l/” in shell creates a whitespace

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Whenever I type `l/` in terminal on OS X (Mavericks), it replaces it with a blank space. I can't seem to find any relevant problems or fixes on Google and I have no idea why this happens.

For example, if I want to type:

```
cd Documents/clinical/
```

It would do:

```
cd Documents/clinica
```

I have tried tab completion and it just does the same thing. This also occurs in ZSH.

I have tried this though, using test folder names:

```
mkdir clinical
cd clinica (automatically turns clinical/ into clinica  )
mkdir specl
cd
cd clinica  spec  (it's turning the l/ into whitespaces for clincal/ and specl/ )
```

…and it does put me in the directory of `/clinical/specl/`.

So I'm really not sure how to get around it … it's kind of frustrating.

Any advice?

---

```
$ stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 32 rows; 120 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: What happens if you try this with a different user account on your Mac (log in via Finder/OSX, not via Terminal)?

Comment: You might have an error introduced in your `tty` special characters. Could you add the output of the following command to your OQ: `stty -a`?

Comment: → Caleb: thank you. My hypothesis of an error within your `tty` special characters was wrong.

Comment: → Caleb: within `Terminal` open `Terminal > Preferences… > Settings > Keyboard`
and look at the `Key` column to see if you didn't inadvertantly introduced a binding for the `"l"` or `"/"` character.

Comment: Hi daniel: I've looked at the Keyboard and there is no binding for the "l" or "/" characters. P.s. Sorry for late reply (was in hospital :/)

Comment: If you run `cat` and then type `l/` at the prompt, do you get the same effect? What encoding do you use in your terminal (latin1, UTF-8, …)? My guess is that this has nothing to do with the shell or the terminal, but it's some kind of input method (which may be active only in certain applications) that turns `l/` into `ł` and possibly other sequences that you haven't discovered yet (what about other Polish characters: do e.g. `z'` and `z.` exhibit similar behavior?).